# Docker-compose: always receive Cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, git-submodules

I have a following project structure:

```
WebApp
  -- docker-compose.yml
  -- Dockerfile
  -- docker
     -- docker-gc
        --Dockerfile
```

`docker/docker-gc` is a git submodule that I have created before using this command:

```
 git submodule add git@github.com:spotify/docker-gc.git docker/docker-gc
```

in docker-compose, I try to run Dockerfile in `docker-gc`. Here is my service:

```
gc:
  container_name: docker-gc
  build: ./docker/docker-gc
  dockerfile: ./docker/docker-gc/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /etc:/etc
```

But I always receive error:

> Cannot locate specified Dockerfile ./docker/docker-gc/Dockerfile

I have tried many ways such as `docker/docker-gc/Dockerfile` or `/docker/docker-gc/Dockerfile` without result. Is this problem related to symlink (due to git submodule nature). Please tell me how can I fix this.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `dockerfile` attribute from the `docker-compose.yaml` file? Shouldn't it use the `Dockerfile` from the specified `build` directory automatically?

Comment: @nwinkler nice. it works. so are there anything wrong here ? in case I want to use different `Dockerfile` ? (for example: `Dockerfile-dev` for dev environment). thanks

Comment: Just specify the filename in the dockerfile attribute, I think it's resolved in the build directory.

Comment: @nwinkler can you tell me clearer about this point? what is docker attribute in docker compose ? thanks

Comment: Please refer to the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dockerfile

Comment: @nwinkler thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your `docker-compose.yaml` file. In version 1 of that format, you can specify both `build` and `dockerfile`. If you provide both, the `dockerfile` attribute denotes the file name that is expected to be found in the directory specified by `build`.

In your case, change the `dockerfile` attribute to just include the filename instead of the same path as in `build`:

```
gc:
  container_name: docker-gc
  build: ./docker/docker-gc
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /etc:/etc
```

Since `Dockerfile` is the default name, you can also simply remove this line:

```
gc:
  container_name: docker-gc
  build: ./docker/docker-gc
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /etc:/etc
```

Please refer to the [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dockerfile) for more info.

Please also note that version 2 of the Docker Compose file format uses a different notion of the `build` parameter.

Comment: super useful :D thanks so much for your clear answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it without Dockerfile in the end. The default should be that it uses a file called "Dockerfile" in the specified folder.